# NFC. Start a activity when scanning NDEF message

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, intentfilter, ndef

I'm trying to start a activity when my smartphone scans an NDEF message. This is my manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.androidbeam"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="16"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.NFC" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.nfc" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.androidbeam.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.androidbeam.SendTextActivity" >

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="com.example.androidbeam.ReceiverNDEFActivity" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                <data
                    android:host="ext"
                    android:pathPrefix="/com.example:externalType"
                    android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Whenever I scan my NDEF message, my main activity launches but I'd like my ReceiverNDEFActivity to launch. I'm not sure why this is the case.

This is my NdefMessage:

```
@Override
public NdefMessage createNdefMessage(NfcEvent event) {
    byte[] payload= new String("Hello");
    String domain = "com.example";
    String type = "externalType"; 
    NdefRecord extRecord = NdefRecord.createExternal(domain, type, payload);

    NdefMessage msg = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { extRecord });
    return msg;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The trick is that NFC Forum external type names are case-insensitive. However, Android's intent filter system is case-**SENSITIVE**. Therefore, you must always use **ALL lower-case** external type names in your intent filters:

```
<activity android:name="com.example.androidbeam.ReceiverNDEFActivity" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data
            android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc"
            android:host="ext"
            android:pathPrefix="/com.example:externaltype" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Note that the `NdefRecord.createExternal(...)` method will automatically convert all type names to lower-case spelling.

Answer (score 0):

The manifest looks pretty much ok I think. Maybe you can try adding

> android:exported="true"

to the activity that should receive the NFC-scanning intent.

```
    <activity android:name="com.example.androidbeam.ReceiverNDEFActivity" >
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.nfc.action.NDEF_DISCOVERED"
            android:exported="true"
            />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data
                android:host="ext"
                android:pathPrefix="/com.example:externalType"
                android:scheme="vnd.android.nfc" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
```

Are you using a NFC-tag to scan from?

Comment: android:exported="true" not working. 

I need peer-to-peer data exchange between a android-powered and non-android-powered devices.

Which of these records should i use,  TNF_MIME_MEDIA or TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE ?

Comment: android:exported="true" belongs to the <activity /> tag and not the <action /> tag. However, the presence of intent filters will automatically set this to true, so no need to specify. As your manifest looks okay, I would assume there is something else going wrong in your code...

Comment: Regarding your question on the record format, I would suggest that you use external types (though particularly WP8 seems to permit auto-launching of apps based on URIs and MS-secific records only). Also note that the type name of external types should be lower-case letters only as external types are case-insensitive (only Android does not implement their intent filters in a case-insensitive way).

Comment: Thanks Michael, looking on the NdefRecord.createExternal source code you can see that it change the type to lowercase. But in the manifest isn't all in lowercase ("externalType").

Comment: So did changing the pathPrefix in the manifest to all lowercase resolve your initial problem?

Comment: Did you maybe also add an Android Application Record (AAR) for your app to the NDEF message? Otherwise I would be still unclear why your MainActivity fired upon the tag...