# NFC Read Tag SMS Service

Tags: android, sms, uri, nfc, ndef

I have written a program in which I am trying to write and read NFC tag, which may help user in sending message. I have successfully written to the tag but whenever I am trying to read, the Tags app shows `vnd.android.nfc://ext/nfclab.com:smsService` but does not allow me to send the message.

**WriteSmsActivity.java:**

```
    @Override
    public void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("Foreground dispatch", "Discovered tag with intent: " + intent);
        Tag tag = intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG);  
        String externalType = "nfclab.com:smsService";
        String smsNumber = smsNumberEditText.getText().toString();
        String smsBody = smsBodyEditText.getText().toString();
        String urlAddress = "sms:"+smsNumber+"?body="+smsBody;
        NdefRecord extRecord = new NdefRecord(NdefRecord.TNF_EXTERNAL_TYPE, externalType.getBytes(), new byte[0], urlAddress.getBytes());
        NdefMessage newMessage = new NdefMessage(new NdefRecord[] { extRecord});
        writeNdefMessageToTag(newMessage, tag);   

    }
}
```

Comment: @MCJ the update you made to your question turned your question into an **entirely new one**. Hence, I rolled back to the previous question. If you want to **ask another question**, open a new question for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android displays the unrecognized NFC Forum external type `nfclab.com:smsService` (note that only lower-case letters should be used for external type names, see [my answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19195723/2425802)), because you stored that record type on your tag. That type is a custom type created by nfclab.com (for rather artificial examples in their book that won't work without a customized reader app) and by no means standardized. Consequently, Android does not know what it should do with that record.

The standard way to store ready-made SMS messages on NFC tags is the sms: URI scheme. Hence, you would typically create a URI record containing your sms: URI:

```
String smsUri = "sms:" + phone_number + "?body=" + text_message;
NdefRecord smsUriRecord = NdefRecord.createUri(smsUri);
```

Since Android 4.1 (or so), such records should be handled automatically by Android and will permit you to open the sms: URI in the default SMS app.