# Use NFC to open Spotify album

Tags: android, android-intent, nfc, spotify

I want to use an NFC tag to open Spotify for Android to a specific album.

If I use the URI `spotify:album:6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDW` then Spotify immediately opens on the homepage. It does not open the specific album.

If I use: `https://open.spotify.com/album/6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDW` It opens via the browser. That's not what I want. I want to open the app directly.

If I use an Android intent `com.spotify.music` it opens the app to the start page.

I've tried using `spotify://album/6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDW` but the problem persists.

Is there a way to use an NFC tag to open the Spotify App directly to an album?

Comment: `intent.data = Uri.parse("spotify:album:6QaVfG1pHYl1z15ZxkvVDWj")`?

Comment: @parth how do I launch that intent from an NDEF message?

Comment: Maybe something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19125161/nfc-start-a-activity-when-scanning-ndef-message)? I am not too sure.

Comment: For the installed Spotify PWA, the solution would be for Spotify to set up [URL handling](https://web.dev/pwa-url-handler/#use) (on desktop, on Android, this wouldn’t even be [necessary](https://web.dev/pwa-url-handler/#enabling-via-about:flags) [the blue text]). They could even integrate the [WebNFC API](https://web.dev/nfc/), but I reckon you got the NFC reading bit going.